# How do I create a new work order in Maximo with a status of INPRG instead of WAPPR by default?

Tags: maximo

Whenever a I create a new work order in Maximo 7.6.0.8, the default status seems to be WAPPR. Is it possible to change the status to INPRG by default for a specific security group or application module?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a fairly simple Automation Script, but Maximo defaults to WAPPR for a reason. In an optimal work management scenario you don't just automatically do work when it comes in, there's typically a triage/prioritization/planning/scheduling effort that takes place before actual work begins. Additionally the INPRG status does some work behind the scenes with things like the Actual Start Date that doesn't necessarily match with when the Work Order is initially created. In short you may save some system work by doing this, but you ultimately lose fidelity in your data.

Comment: Not really an answer because you don't say how this can be done with an automation script. I did consider an escalation as that seems to be a documented option to change status after the work order is created. Some use cases require simplicity and  reducing all the steps requires to get something done improves adoption.

Comment: Maybe something like this? https://a3jgroup.com/launch-automation-script-on-new-record-creation-in-maximo/ or this? https://maximodeploy.blogspot.com/2020/09/change-status-of-child-work-orders-or.html

Comment: The question you asked is: "Is it possible...", so I'd argue that an answer was given. Both of those links have components you could use, the first creates the trigger (technically not a launch point since it's using the name to trigger the script), and the second includes some of the methods you need (specifically changeStatus()).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. see below.

1. Go to Automation Scripts Application
2. Go to More Actions Select Create
3. Then Select Script (No Launch Point)
4. Name the script OBJECTNAME.NEW i.e. WORKORDER.NEW

Syntax using Python:

```
# Import Packages & Classes
from psdi.mbo import MboConstants
# Upon Creation of New Work Order Record Set The Status to INPRG
# Regardless if the STATUS field is read only or not.
if app == 'WOTRACK':
   mbo.setValue("STATUS","INPRG",MboConstants.NOACCESSCHECK)
```